# Wrap inner HTML partially

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering is there a way to convert this:

```
<body>
    Foo
    Bar
    <div>Abc</div>
    <div>Xyz</div>
</body>
```

To this:

```
<body>
    <div id="new">
        Foo
        Bar
    </div>
    <div>Abc</div>
    <div>Xyz</div>
</body>
```

As a novice, I know basic things about `innerHTML` and jQuery `wrap`, but code like this one:

```
var foo = document.body.innerHTML;
console.log(foo);
```

gives me the full body, include `Abc` and `Xyz` divs. So, it doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Should newline characters between `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` be preserved? Or should only `.textContent` of `#text` nodes be set as `.innerHTML` of dynamically created `<div>` element?

Comment: I'm working on Markdown extension for Chrome, so I think, the newline characters should be preserved...

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, maybe I forgot to mention you in previous comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `contents().filter()` to retrieve the text nodes and then `wrapAll()` to place them inside a new `div` element. Try this:

```js
$('body').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent != '';
}).wrapAll('<div id="new" />');
```

```css
/* only to show the new div exists... */
#new { border: 1px solid #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Foo
Bar
<div>Abc</div>
<div>Xyz</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But as I understand, it doent's preserve newline character between Foo and Bar. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Do you need that newline? Multiple whitespace is irrelevant in html

Comment: Not want to bother you, but may be you could also show how to include `Abc` div into filtering, but without `Xyz` div? In any case, I accepted the answer.

Comment: Sure - you can use `filter()` to do that too: `$('div').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == 'Abc'; });` although it would be much better if you could put a class or id on the div and select it by that instead

Answer (score 3):

A non-jQuery solution:

You can iterate over all child nodes of the body and move every text node to a new element until you reach the first element node. Example:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'new';
var childNodes = document.body.childNodes;
while (childNodes[0].nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
  div.appendChild(childNodes[0]);
}
document.body.insertBefore(div, childNodes[0]);
```

```css
#new {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Foo
Bar
<div>Abc</div>
<div>Xyz</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But as I understand, it doent's preserve newline character between Foo and Bar. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It does preserve them. But browsers treat line breaks as ordinary white space. If you want to *render* newlines  use a `pre` element instead of a `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.contents()`, `.filter()`, `.prependTo()`. To preserve new line characters, set `#new` `css` `white-space` property to `pre`.

```js
var nodes = $("body").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3 && /Foo|Bar/.test(this.textContent) 
});

$("<div></div>", {
  id:"new",
  html: nodes,
  css: {whiteSpace: "pre"}
}).prependTo("body")
```

```css
#new {
  color: sienna;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

Foo

Bar

<div>Abc</div>

<div>Xyz</div>

</body>
```

Comment: @jsv See updated post.